# Write millions of lines to a file - Python, Dataframes and Redis

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas, redis

I have the following code snippet that reads a CSV into a dataframe, and writes out key-values pairs to a file in a Redis protocol-compliant fashion, i.e. `SET key1 value1`. The code is piecemeal and I have tried to use multiprocessing, though I am not sure of its performance (gains).

The CSV has about 6 million lines, that is read into a dataframe pretty quickly (under 2 minutes). The output file has 12 million lines (2 lines per line of the input file). This takes about 50 minutes to complete. Can any part of my code be optimized/changed to make this run faster? Once the file is complete, loading it to Redis takes less than 90 seconds. The bottleneck really is in writing to the file.

I was looking into loading all the strings I generate into a dataframe and then use the to_csv() function to dump it to a file, but I'm not sure of how its performance will be.

```
filepath = '/path/to/file.csv'

def df_to_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    f = open('output_file', 'w')
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df['col1'].iloc[i] != '':
            key1 = str_const1+str(df['col1'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1 = df['col_n+1'].iloc[i]

            key1a = str_const1a+str(df['col1'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1a = df['col_n+2'].iloc[i]

            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)

        if df['col2'].iloc[i] != '':
            key1 = str_const2+str(df['col2'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1 = df['col_n+1'].iloc[i]

            key1a = str_const2a+str(df['col2'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1a = df['col_n+2'].iloc[i]

            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
        if df['col3'].iloc[i] != '':
            key1 = str_const3+str(df['col3'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1 = df['col_n+1'].iloc[i]

            key1a = str_const3a+str(df['col3'].iloc[i])+str(df['col4'].iloc[i])+str(df['col5'].iloc[i])+...+str(df['col_n'].iloc[i])
            val1a = df['col_n+2'].iloc[i]

            print('SET {0} {1}\nSET {0} {1}'.format(key1, val1, key1a, val1a), file = f)
    f.close()

p = Process(target = df_to_file)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: Where are `string1`, `string2`, `string1a` and `string2a` defined?

Comment: Your function definition is also lacking the arguments, making this code broken.

Comment: This code is broken in many ways. Flagged to be closed :)

Comment: I've given a more complete picture of the code, to help get better answers.

Comment: I couldn’t see any difference between Key1 and key1a.?

Comment: @GürkanÇetin: Sorry! I add a constant string before I do all this, and so, there is a difference between the two. That string varies according to what I'm setting as key1 or key1a.

Comment: Alright, then just a small tip, don’t know how useful but you can save some cpu and ram clocks by defining a temporary variable and saying key1= const1 + tempVar, and key1a=const1a + tempVar, instead of concatenating several strings in two different lines. (Although the main bottleneck is the writing process.)

Comment: @Graipher and others - I have provided a complete working solution here. I have only masked the true column names. This code works. It's just really slow. I put this question and got an answer on SO as well and that works MUCH faster than my code here. I've only left it here to see if there are answers that are even faster. If you can point out exactly what I need to improve, I will do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a hard core Pythonista, but a few points I can think of are:

- The assignments of `key1`, `val1`, ... appear unneeded as they're used only once in the call to `format()`
- Terminate each `if` with a `continue`, or use `else`, as it appears that only one branch is executed in each iteration of the range. Order the conditions according to data's expected distribution if possible (i.e. most frequently evaluated to true condition comes first)
- Try writing less, e.g. see if you can use `MSET` to shave a few bytes in each iteration (times millions this may have significant effects ;))

Lastly, it looks that you're not using the last two arguments you pass to `format`, so if that isn't a typo you can remove them as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am following the 2nd part of the second one already. One of the reasons I'm not writing to Redis directly is because, well, I already tried that and it didn't work out too well, but more importantly, I'm writing this in the Redis protocol format, which specifies a strict "SET key value" per line file to be fed to it. I then pipe this file through to another python program and then into Redis where it loads these 12 million keys in under 2 minutes.